# How do you block referrer logging in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, privacy, http-referrer

I've searched though all the settings I can find in Chrome but can't determine how to disable referrer logging for both HTTP and HTTPS requests. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this Google Chrome by using the NOREF extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dkpkjedlegmelkogpgamcaemgbanohip

Description as provided by the extension developer:

> This extension adds a rel=noreferrer attribute to every  link on
>   any web page being viewed. It blocks sending referer headers to
>   landing pages, thereby strengthening privacy while browsing.
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Referrer (aka referer) is a header value transmitted by the browser to
>   a target web site when a link is clicked on. It contains the URL of
>   the referring web site where the link was clicked on. Some users may
>   not wish to share that information with websites while they browse due
>   to privacy concerns. This Chrome extension blocks the transmission of
>   the referrer header to sites, by adding rel=noreferrer to every link
>   on web pages.

Another alternate way would be to launch Google Chrome using --no-referrers assuming you are using Windows.

> "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --no-referrers

Answer (score 2):

Just configure the shortcut to Chrome with the suffix shown above (--no-referers) and you'll always have them off without installing any third party software. Which is specially good, if you are using MS Windows.